# can we say textfile is a database?

Tags: database

Can we say textfile is a database?  As we know that a database is a collection of data
and a database allows easy retrieval and manipulation, but we can do these things with 
a textfile.  So is a text file is a database?

Comment: I smell an Impossible Question -- http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.  They can even be treated as entities and used in Unix text tools in relational terms (join,cat(union),grep(select),cut(project)) and use `awk` (and perl) for a traditional record-by-record predicate/action programming model (SQL).

I would not however, call a collection of text files a database MANAGEMENT system.

Answer (score 5):

I'd call it a datastore instead. Maybe even a datasource.

Database has the connotation of organization or order. A collection of things in their places. Sometimes they even store non-textual data.

Comment: but we can also stored interrelated and meaningfull data in text file...for instance we can store session information in text file...we can also store record of a student which can we imported by sql server 2008.......can u define non textual data please ?

Answer (score 1):

Database is more than just storage. It is also access to that storage which implies: security, authorization, transactions, relations, etc

Comment: but we can also put security, authorization.......but i want to ask about database .....relation comes under relational database....

Answer (score 0):

[Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)

> A collection of (usually) organized
>   information in a regular structure,
>   usually but not necessarily in a
>   machine-readable format accessible by
>   a computer; A software program for
>   storing, retrieving and manipulating a
>   database.

A text file does not fit this description.

Comment: Acording to you if we have a software for manipulate a file then that file will become database.......?
of course there is some software that manipulate and retrive ,modifyu data in text file....while we import text file with the help of sql server that's means what at  that position we do retriving process so i want to say there is some software that insert data in text file..........

Comment: text files are text files. databases are databases. You can't my any stretch of imagination say ANY text file is a database. Some files that can be edited using text editors can be used to import data into databases does not mean all text files are databases -- Eg: 'You're a guy -> You can make websites -- This does not imply all guys universally from hereon-forth will be called web-developers.'

Comment: Incomplete comparison.  Binary files are binary files.  These files can be tablespace storage for your database or your favorite birthday party JPEG.

Comment: What you're saying is apples and oranges are both fruits, so, they're the same. What I'm saying is. They are the same because they are fruits but apples are still apples and oranges still oranges. And if someone asks (me/you) can apples be considered oranges? I would say either they don't know anything, or, they're just screwing around with your head for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Calling it a database may not be invalid, but it will be misleading to a lot of people. Naming something a database often raises the expectation that you can interface against it with some sort of SQL among other things.

Answer (score 0):

A text file can **contain** a database (or part of it), but the file itself is just a medium.

I assume this is the essence of your question: Is the data on a loose text file a database without DBMS (database management system).

## What is a database?

The bare minimum **"Database"** definition entails is data itself being organized/structured, so **the answer is yes, it can be**. DBMS, despite not being mandatory, is the thing that gives databases most of their utility (read, write, indexing, encryptions, relation, validation, etc.).

- Storage format is irrelevant. As long as you/DBMS can consistently write and read entries it works. Data can be in plain text, encrypted, and even disorganized to an extent as long as the tools that deal with it know how to interpret it.
- Storage medium is irrelevant. It can be plain text `.txt` file, a file without extension, or it can be direct binary code and it can be on any type of storage device.
- Who/what interacts with the data is irrelevant. So whether you wrote it in notepad or DBMS generated it makes no difference.

**A simple way to look at it:** the files DBMS produces when storing data contain the database itself. DATA is the database regardless of where/how the data is stored or who formed it. The database doesn't stop being a database if you uninstall DBMS (even if you lose the tool to interpret it). If you're capable of manually accessing/editing the data (without corrupting it), it still doesn't stop being a database.

## Why it's a moot point

- If you only access the data in your your text file database using notepad (instead of DBMS), you're putting in extra effort to keep it maintained correctly without reaping any of the benefits.
- If you are using a DBMS then whatever file/data format it's a conventional database and not just a loose text file.